# Does json have different sub formats?

Tags: php, json

Is this JSON broken or does it have different formats?

If yes, what format is it?

If no, why doesn't json_decode work on this? It returns an empty array.

http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/ProgramDataHandler.ashx?type=6&sortValue=DATE&week=14062&day=-1&sort=-1&sortDir=1&groupId=-1&np=0&sport=1

Comment: I'm going to say yes, it's broken because it crashes the tools I use to try and format it.

Comment: @travisj can you parse it with json_decode?

Comment: Not valid JSON because the keys are not quoted.  http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @hammerstein it crashed mine too :(

Comment: yeah, I'm starting to think that my browsers are hosed!

Comment: @jmoerdyk can you post a quick fixed version?

Comment: Besides jmoerdyk's comment, PHP's implementation of `json_decode` expects strings to be quoted with `"` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Regex solves your problem:

```
j = re.sub(r"{\s*(\w+):", r'{"\1":', j)
j = re.sub(r",\s*(\w+):", r',"\1":', j)
j = j.replace("'", '"')
```

Answer (score 1):

The format is not correct.  This tool will correct it for you.  Go to here: http://jsonformat.com/#jsondataurllabel

Copy in your json and let it parse.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PEAR Services_JSON package installed, and in your include path, it will parse your file correctly without needing to modify the source JSON:

```
<?php

$my_file = file_get_contents('http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/ProgramDataHandler.ashx?type=6&sortValue=DATE&week=14062&day=-1&sort=-1&sortDir=1&groupId=-1&np=0&sport=1');

$json = new Services_JSON();

$decoded = $json->decode($my_file);

print_r($decoded);
```